# Vitest CLI not recognized

Tags: vite, vitest

installed `pnpm add -D vitest` and `pnpm add -D @vitest/ui` in my project dir, when i try `vitest --ui`, I get this error

```
vitest : The term 'vitest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your dependencies are installed by running `pnpm install`, and then try adding a new script to your `package.json` file for running your tests. For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "test": "vitest --ui",
  },
```

Enter the `pnpm run test` command in your terminal to run the script.

Comment: without install to global , this is the best way

Answer (score 3):

You should install the package globally using npm or yarn. Don't forget to use `sudo` if you are in Mac or Linux.

```
npm install -g vitest
```